# Is Berlusconi being used as a scarecrow to make other presidential candidates more acceptable in Italy?

Tags: presidential-election, italy

If you type in a search engine "Berlusconi presidential candidate" or "Draghi presidential candidate" you will find a lot of references to the upcoming presidential elections in Italy. In the Italian press these are the most common names that were cited as candidates in the past two months, but none of them is popular.
Given Berlusconi's criminal record he is really an unlikely candidate, he might be still elected with the votes of the center right coalition and the vote of the [MCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Star_Movement), but these parties might as well vote for Mario Draghi. After all both of the candidates are well accepted by the Italian oligarchic families which control of the major Italian newspapers and have a say over who can be cited in the press or not.

So, we have only two candidates, both unpopular, both backed by the same people. But given how polarising is Berlusconi, how difficult would be his election and how insulted many Italians would feel by being represented by such a character isn't it likely that his name is just being used to scare the Italians (who can vote since the president will be elected by the MPs) and make Draghi more acceptable?

---

Wikipedia article: [2022 Italian presidential election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Italian_presidential_election)